# XPath get element with text in child element

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I would like to match a `<button>` element with a certain text, which is sometimes closed in another element within the button, eg.:

```
<div @class="buttonset"> 
  <button>Close</button>
</div>

<div @class="buttonset"> 
  <button>
    <span>Close</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

The xpath query `//div[@class='modal-buttonset']/button[text()='Cancel']` gives me only result from the highest level.

How to match the text on all levels?

Comment: Attributes in XML and HTML do not begin with `@` -- your example confuses markup syntax with XPath syntax.   Hopefully that's a question typo, not your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
//div/button[descendant::text()="Close"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//button[normalize-space() = 'Close']
```

will select all `button` elements whose space-normalized string value is `'Close'`, regardless of any additional wrapper elements, as requested.